# Multiply a set of columns in data frame R to another set of columns

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 156 variables and I would like to multiply a subset of those variables to another subset of the 156. How can I do that: The variables are of the following form:

ID||quantity_1||quantity_2||...||quantity_156||priceperunit_q1||...priceperunit||q156

essentially I would like to multiply each quantity by its priceperunit

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far, what doesn't work in your code? It will be easier if you post an example of your dataset. You can use `dput()` in R and copy it in your question.

Comment: @RobertoT I used expand.grid() with a combination of filter to create a data.frame with 1 columns which contains character strings of the form var1*priceperunit_var1...varn*price_perunit_varn
Then I want to write a loop (or some iteration) to pass each of those strings so that the result is the product

I TRY ADDING MY CODE HERE IT SAYS TOO LONG

Comment: Perhaps a subset of the final dataset you want to work with will be enough. You don't need to paste all the code you used. Just the step you are having issues and an example of the data in that step.

Comment: @RobertoTthis approach seems to be best but the problem is that it discards my ID variables

Answer (score 1):

Given you first have all the quantity columns and then all the priceperunit columns in the correct order, you can make two different data sets and multiply them using `mapply`, like this. The result set will contain the product of the two columns, rename this if needed:

```
quantity_1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
quantity_2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
quantity_3 <- c(1, 2, 3)
quantity_40 <- c(1, 2, 3)
priceperunit_1 <- c(20, 20, 20)
priceperunit_2 <- c(30, 30, 30)
priceperunit_3 <- c(15, 15, 15)
priceperunit_40 <- c(1.25, 1.25, 1.65)

df <- data.frame(quantity_1, quantity_2, quantity_3, quantity_40, 
                 priceperunit_1, priceperunit_2, priceperunit_3, priceperunit_40)
df
#>   quantity_1 quantity_2 quantity_3 quantity_40 priceperunit_1 priceperunit_2
#> 1          1          1          1           1             20             30
#> 2          2          2          2           2             20             30
#> 3          3          3          3           3             20             30
#>   priceperunit_3 priceperunit_40
#> 1             15            1.25
#> 2             15            1.25
#> 3             15            1.65

as.data.frame(mapply("*", 
                     df[, grep("^quantity", names(df))], 
                     df[, grep("^priceperunit", names(df))]))
#>   quantity_1 quantity_2 quantity_3 quantity_40
#> 1         20         30         15        1.25
#> 2         40         60         30        2.50
#> 3         60         90         45        4.95
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to reshape your data from `wide` to `long` format, see `?reshape`. This will also help you keeping your original data format.

The trick is to store all your price and all your quantity data into the same 2 columns, but records will be differentiated thanks to the newly created `time` variable of `reshape` (1 to 156 according to your post).

You can then compute the volume (price x quantity), and go back to the `wide` format if desired.

See the reproducible example below.

```
df <- data.frame(price1 = 1:10,
                 price2 = 11:20,
                 quantity1 = c(1:5, 1:5),
                 quantity2 = c(5:9, 5:9))

df_long <- reshape(df,
                   direction = "long",
                   v.names = c("price", "quantity"),
                   varying = list(paste0("price", 1:2), paste0("quantity", 1:2)),
                   times = c("1", "2"))

df_long$volume <- df_long$price*df_long$quantity

df_wide <- reshape(df_long,
                   direction = "wide",
                   v.names = c("price", "quantity", "volume"),
                   timevar = "time",
                   sep = "")
```

Comment: another way is to pivot longer the quantities (keeping the ID variables) creating a unit ID hence original ID and unit ID are the ID variables in long data. Do same for prices. The full join. Multiply and then pivot wider. It worked well for me so that's what I'll use